# Polar form to cartesian

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

Let $\Gamma$ be a circle that passes through the origin. Show that we can find real numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $\Gamma$ is the graph of
$r = 2s \cos (\theta + t).$

I know this has to be converted to a cartesian equation, but how do I do this, and what do I do after?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: For the general circle described by the equation $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$, centered at $(h,k)$ with radius $r$, the circle will pass through the origin provided that $(h,k)\neq(0,0)$ and $r=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$. You can try to work backwards by setting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

A circle that passes through the origin can be expressed as
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=a^2+b^2,$$
i.e.
$$x^2-2ax+y^2-2by=0$$
for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $(a,b)\not=(0,0)$.

Here, setting $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ gives you
$$r^2\cos^2\theta-2ar\cos\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta-2br\sin\theta=0,$$
i.e.
$$r=2a\cos\theta+2b\sin\theta.$$
Since this can be written as 
$$r=2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot \cos\theta\cdot \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}-2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot\sin\theta\cdot\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$
setting $s=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\cos t=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\sin t=-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ gives you
$$r=2s\cos(\theta+t).$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $x(\theta)=r(\theta) \cos \theta$ and $y(\theta)=r(\theta) \sin \theta$. Based on that you can use trigonometric formulaes to compute the cartesian coordinates $(x(\theta),y(\theta))$ and recognize the equation of a circle.